# Trace inline cache miss v8

Tags: javascript, gdb, v8

I want to find function that call inline cache miss ( at most first )
so, I find inline cache miss function:

```
RUNTIME_FUNCTION(StoreIC_Miss) {
TimerEventScope<TimerEventIcMiss> timer(isolate);

HandleScope scope(isolate);
DCHECK(args.length() == 3);
StoreIC ic(IC::NO_EXTRA_FRAME, isolate);
Handle<Object> receiver = args.at<Object>(0);
Handle<Name> key = args.at<Name>(1);
ic.UpdateState(receiver, key);
Handle<Object> result;
ASSIGN_RETURN_FAILURE_ON_EXCEPTION(
   isolate, result, ic.Store(receiver, key, args.at<Object>(2)));
return *result;
}
```

And I am debugging above mentioned function in GDB and look stack ( backtrace )

However, stack is in ??()

```
#0  v8::internal::StoreIC::Store (this=0x7fffffffc4d8, object=..., name=...,     
value=..., 
store_mode=v8::internal::Object::CERTAINLY_NOT_STORE_FROM_KEYED) at   
../src/ic/ic.cc:1583
#1  0x0000000000c9e95b in v8::internal::__RT_impl_StoreIC_Miss (args=...,  
isolate=0x2133910) at ../src/ic/ic.cc:2504
#2  0x0000000000c9e792 in v8::internal::StoreIC_Miss (args_length=3,  
args_object=0x7fffffffc620, isolate=0x2133910)
at ../src/ic/ic.cc:2493
#3  0x0000118e1bd060bb in ?? ()
#4  0x0000118e1bd06001 in ?? ()
...
#52 0x0000118e1bd836fb in ?? ()
```

I want to find invoke or call part that call #2 StoreIC_Miss function.

Answer (score 0):

[You need to enable gdb jit](https://code.google.com/p/v8-wiki/wiki/GDBJITInterface) to see jitted frames. Build with `gdbjit=on` and then run V8 with `--gdbjit`  flag.